# Where should my .bash_profile file be for Python to update?

Tags: python, macos, unix, osx-snow-leopard

I'm using Mac OSX 10.6.8 Snow Leopard and I think I've got everything I need to install Python 3.3.2, but when I type `python` into Terminal it still says I have 2.6.1. This is because it can't find the path to the newer version, and this should be fixed by adding the following to .bash_profile:

```
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3.2/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

I've already done it (and run the `cat` command on it several times just to check), but it keeps saying the same thing. I suppose my .bash_profile file and/or Python 3.3.2 folder might not be in the right directories? .bash_profile is in `/Users/mac` (home) and the Python folder is in `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions`. Should they be somewhere else?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `python3` to run `python3`, and also restart your shell after modifying `.bash_profile` or do `source .bash_profile` to load the new settings without restarting the shell.

```
$ which python3
/usr/bin/python3
```

Example:

```
$ cat so.py
#!/usr/bin/python3
print("hello, world!")
$ chmod +x so.py
$ ./so.py
hello, world!
```

Comment: I've already restarted it and the same thing keeps happening. Is it possible to make 3 the default version? I think I can't run the programmes I write because of this.

Comment: @reggaelizard it is possible to run program using py3 without removing py2, add a shebang line on top those programs that points to py3: `#!/usr/bin/python3`. or use `python3 my_program.py`.

Comment: @reggaelizard you can also temporarily make `python` execute `python3` by making an alias in shell. `$ alias python='python3'`. To make it permanent add this alias to your `bash_profile` file.

Comment: Typing `#!/usr/bin/python3` seems to work, so thanks again for the help! I need to figure out how to actually make it display the results but Terminal isn't printing out any error messages so I think it's good.

Comment: I think I got what I wanted with print statements, definitely accepted.